# How to change color of detected object in real time using swift, coreml, vision?

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, apple-vision

How can I get the actual shape of the detected object, for example, to change its color?
In the picture below

[image: picture]

you can see that banana is detected and was put in Rect, but how can I get the actual detected shape of it, for example, to make the banana pink?
Thanks

I found out that it is called semantic segmentation.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you try to classify objects with machine learning. But you model is only trained to recognize some pretrained objects. Not to give you the shape of an object.

Comment: Well, that's not my model, image is just for the example, that's why I am asking how to make it to give me the shape/location of the object.